# Is there a way to catch all exceptions in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I catch all types of exceptions in one catch block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859/how-can-i-catch-all-types-of-exceptions-in-one-catch-block)

In C++ is there a way to catch ALL exceptions?  If so, what would the syntax for that be?

Merci

Comment: You need to clarify; do you mean *all* exceptions or *all unhandled* exceptions ?  After all, you could wrap your entry point in a try-catch block as Seth mentioned, but if there is inner code that explicitly handles the exception and lets the program continue, it won't hit your entry point catch block.

Comment: If you're doing this to debug an exception there is an easier way in Visual Studio; On the debug menu go to the Exceptions option and you can select options to VS stop when ever an exception occurs, even if it's handled, and a few other things.

Comment: And by the way, that's typically "poor form".  Especially if you do something like `try { ... } catch (...) { ; }` (i.e. silently eat any/all possible exceptions).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can catch all exceptions that were not handled (and not rethrown) by inner `try`/`catch` blocks by `catch`ing `...`:

```
try {
    // do some stuff
} catch (...) {
    // catch any exceptions that weren't handled and/or rethrown in the try block
}
```

You can also combine this with other `catch`es, but make sure they are above the `catch (...)` or they will be masked by the catch-all (and you should get a compiler error).

Comment: This doesn't necessarily catch *any* exception because ones that are handled in inner try-catch blocks and don't halt program execution aren't bubbled to this.

Comment: @RussC that is true, but catching literally every exception isn't possible with C++.

Comment: Agreed, but your wording is unintentionally misleading; just wanted to make sure that OP was aware of exception scope.

Comment: @RussC Ok, I clarified it a bit.

Answer (score 5):

You can catch all exceptions like this

```
try{
    // ...
} catch (...) {
    // ...
}
```

However a more useful thing to do is to catch specific exceptions and then finally fall to the (...)

```
try{
    // ...
} catch (const std::exception& ex) {
    // ...
} catch (const std::string& ex) {
    // ...
} catch (...) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot catch ALL exceptions, because you cannot catch exceptions that have already been caught by another handler nested within your `try/catch` block.